# Jar file which contains the Javadoc?

Tags: jar, javadoc

Is it possible to create a jar file which contains the javadoc ?

For now, I'm creating a jar file & javadoc folder.
1. I want to create a jar file that contains the javadoc , can I ?
2. Can I do so without attaching the source code into the jar file ? (just the jar with javadoc) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. A jar file is just a zip with a manifest and additional features. You can put any type of file in it, including images, html files etc... All you have to do is jar your javadoc folder exactly as you would do for a classes folder.

Comment: ok, If I will do it, how would I configure the eclipse to show the javadoc of the current methods of this file ?

Comment: In your Eclipse project's build path, in the "Libraries" tab, you can expand each jar and associate a javadoc folder or archive with it